# How to keep what was typed in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using a Javascript autocomplete widget, which properly shows the suggestion list as I type, however when I press the down key to browse the list, my current input is erased.

[image]
`SERVIÇO OU PRODUTO` is a placeholder.

While this is not my exact issue, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boniattirodrigo/vag3jhmo/) should demonstrate the problem. After typing a letter and pressing the down key, it replaces my input with the selection.

This is my code:

```
$.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super();
    },
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
        var t = '',
            result = '';

        $.each(this.options.columns, function() {
            t = '<span>' + item[0] + ' - R$ ' + item[1] + '</span>';
        });

        result = $('<li></li>')
            .data(item)
            .append(t)
            .appendTo(ul);
        return result;
    }
});

$("#my-input").mcautocomplete({
    columns: my-columns,
    source: my-info,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = (ui.item[0]);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cancel the focus event:

```
focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

[Working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsznqs19/1/)

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boniattirodrigo/vag3jhmo/) you provided does cancel the event but then nullifies its own action right away by using this:

```
$("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
```

See [Autocomplete Widget - event - focus](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus)

> **focus( event, ui )**
>
> Type: autocompletefocus
>
> Triggered when focus is moved to an item (not selecting). The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the focused item, though only if the event was triggered by a keyboard interaction.
>
> Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the menu item from being focused.
>
> **Code examples**
>
> Initialize the autocomplete with the focus callback specified:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
>     focus: function( event, ui ) {}
> });
> ```
>
> Bind an event listener to the autocompletefocus event:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).on( "autocompletefocus", function( event, ui ) {} );
> ```

Comment: That is exactly that I've looking. Thanks!